# Error when uploading image with laravel and intervention package

Tags: php, laravel

before storing a file on my laravel app I want to proccess the image with Intervention package, and then upload it to /uploads folder inside my public disk however I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:Can't write image data to path (uploads)
```

My store method

```
$image = $request->file($name);
            $extension = $image->guessExtension();

            $resized = Image::make($image)->resize(640, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio(); 
                $constraint->upsize(); })
                ->encode('jpg',75);
                //->stream();
            
            
            $file = $resized;
            $filename = 'file-'.Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y-H-i').'-'.Str::random(3).'-'.mt_rand('000','999').'.'.$extension;
            $file->save('/uploads');
```

Comment: What error. please provide more information.

Comment: edite OP with correct info

Comment: I wish you would put the codes more completely so that we can guide you more easily!